# How to parse this json data

Tags: javascript, json

I have got data in this format:

```
[
    "leaf",
    [
        {
            "name": "Regular pack, 100 gm"
        },
        {
            "name": "Large family pack, 200 gm"
        }
    ]
]
```

How can i parse it and get the arrays present under it ??

I have tried it using , but its not working (getting undefined error )

```
 for (var k = 0; k < responseinner[0].leaf.length; k++) {

}
```

could you please help , thanks in advance .

Comment: use `$.each()` to iterate through your json data

Comment: I guess you want `[ "leaf":[] ]`, notice `"leaf",` thus you are getting undefined error

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is wrong. You have an array that contains one string, and one array of objects.

what you probably need, is an object, containing an array named leaf.

```
{
    "leaf": [
        {
            "name": "Regular pack, 100 gm"
        },
        {
            "name": "Large family pack, 200 gm"
        }
    ]
}
```

Iterating over this data is easy:

```
for (var k = 0; k < responseinner.leaf.length; k++) {
    var obj = responseinner.leaf[k];
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i am still gettting  , Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: A good question is, where are you getting your JSON data from? Is it from a js file? Are you calling, via ajax, a PHP file(that may or may not access it from your data base)? In fact, where do you define what your "responseinner" is?

Comment: That error is because responseinner doesn't exist in the area of code you're working on. post more of your code so we can see the problem